# Linker script not detecting overlapping regions

Tags: linker, ld

I have developed a linker script which has overlapping regions. I want the linker to produce an error for overlapping regions. I am using --check-sections command line parameter but it doesn't work. Here is a small portion of my script file:

```
.region1 (DDR_ORG) (NOLOAD) :
{
    . = . + 0x1000;
} > DDR

.region2 (DDR_ORG) (NOLOAD) :
{
    . = . + 0x100000;
} > DDR
```